# Is there possible to get accurate value for image average mean of the single row/column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I just try out the numpy to find the mean for each column and row of the image, but it show up like a lot of number

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
shape = np.shape(img)
pixels = np.array(img)


column_means = np.mean(pixels, axis=0) //can change axis = 1 for row
column_max = np.max(pixels, axis=0) //can change axis = 1 for row
column_min = np.min(pixels, axis=0) //can change axis = 1 for row
column_subtract = column_max - column_min //can change axis = 1 for row


print(shape)
print(column_means)
print(column_max)
print(column_min)
print(column_subtract)
```

[Here is sample photo I'm working on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoH81.png)

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. `column_means` is an array containing the mean values of each column. If you want just one column, index into that array.

Comment: actually I would to know each of the column/row so that i could know which is maximum value and minimum value of the mean and subtract it. But the results shows a lot of value I'm not sure which to take it

Comment: why import cv2 in the example if it is not used ?